# Block chat in Rocket League

Tags: steam, rocket-league

My 12yo son plays "Rocket League" on Steam, however he has started chatting in game to some people who have terrible language that I'd prefer my son doesn't pick up (at least not this young!), and so in an effort to keep him safer I'd like to block the chat (text chat) in Rocket League and possibly in Steam client as well (I think they are linked).

Is it possible to completely block the chat?  I am aware it can be done in-game, but of course this can be fairly easily un-done again too.  I'm wondering whether there is a config file I could edit to turn it off or block it somehow?

Comment: This is possible on the xbox one in gameplay options, simply set chat to none.

Answer (score 9):

Even if you change the config files manually, it can be undone from inside the game.

I think that simply telling your son to either not use the words he sees (let's be honest: he'll get exposed to it sooner or later) are not nice words or just disabling chat inside the game and telling him to not change the settings explaining your worries should suffice.

So, to block it from inside the game, open Options, go to Gameplay and set "Text Chat" (and "Voice Chat") as disabled.

Comment: and FWIW I couldn't find the option in any of the config files; none of the files even changed when I changed the setting in-game and quit. There is a remote possibility the game would refuse to change the option if it can't save it to a file, but it's unlikely, and like I said, couldn't find such config anyway.

Comment: +1 for talking to his son about not using those words and explaining why.  OP may be able to solve the problem for this game (and maybe even all Steam games) but every time he starts playing a new game on a new platform, the same issue will arise.  People on the internet as a@@holes (wink).  Give a kid a fish vs teach a kid to fish, and all that.